# Ionic can't make statusbar overlay

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having some issues with Ionic on Android. I think the problem occurred when I updated the Ionic version for my app. Problem is that the status bar doesn't overlay the webview. I have tried setting the `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` preference to `true` in config.xml and I've tried calling the different methods of  the global `StatusBar` object  with no success. I can control the status bar's background color and visibility, but I can't get it to overlay the webview. This is what it looks like right now[image: Android Ionic Screenshot statusbar]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` method in cordova-plugin-statusbar [is only supported by the iOS platform](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#user-content-statusbaroverlayswebview):

> **StatusBar.overlaysWebView** 
>   On iOS 7, make the statusbar overlay or not overlay the WebView.
>
> ```
> StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>   On iOS 7, set to false to make the statusbar appear like iOS 6. Set the style and background color to suit using the other functions.
>
> **Supported Platforms**
>   iOS

Here are some other methods. Check the link below (but it doesn't seem to work anymore)
http://www.martinadamko.sk/posts/translucent-bar-android-278

Or

How about this?
The easiest way to do this is as follows:

```
/* ionic 2 app.ts */
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, ionicBootstrap } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
})
export class App {
  private rootPage: any;

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.rootPage = LandingPage;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();

      // Status bar theme for android
      if (platform.is('android')) {
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#c42626');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The result is like:

[image]